# Extract lat long point values from EASE2 without reprojection

Tags: raster, r, coordinate-system

I have the following file:
[EASE2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwkLXkUMkLd4ZXp0ZTJScjQ5S28)
and want to extract the values for this geographic location `(148.1, -35.6)` #lon lat.
How can I do this without the need for reprojecting the `ease grid` file into `geographic` projection?

Here is an example code:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster (file)
e <- data.frame(148.1, -35.6)
ext <- extract(r, e)
```

Answer (score 2):

Transform the point to the coordinate system of the raster.

Make the point into a SpatialPointsDataFrame in the lat-long coordinate system:

```
> e <- data.frame(x=148.1, y=-35.6, id=1)
> coordinates(e)=~x+y
> projection(e)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
```

then transform to the coordinates of the raster:

```
> et = spTransform(e,projection(r))
> plot(r)
> points(et,col="red",pch=19)
```

Shows me the point is on the Australian south-east coast. Extract:

```
> extract(r,et)

1
```

Comment: Thank you, that was one of my options, but I have seen people converting the lat lon into the number of rows and column in the ease gird raster and then extract the values. In that case you also get different result from this. What is the best approach to deal with this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to illustrate this? Do you mean the coordinates are converted as if the raster is a uniform grid in lat-long? That might work, or it might not, depending on how the raster is projected.